# how count number of affected rows in listen method - laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am use the listen method of laravel  for make a log for every queries. I get all sql queries like that:

```
\DB::listen(function($q) {
    $query = $q->sql;
    //Save in logn
});
```

I want get the number of columns modified when query is an update or delete.

Can you help me?

Comment: It's not possible to get the number of affected rows like this. It is only available from the query: `$affected = $query->update([...]);`

Answer (score -1):

in your controller

**(1) using Eloquent:**

```
 use App\Project;

 public function totalprojects()
        {
            $total_projects = Project::count();
            return view('summarys.summary')->with(['total'=>$total_projects]);
        }
```

**(2) using Query Builder:**

```
use DB;
  public function totalprojects()
            {
                $total_projects = DB::table('projects')->count();
                return view('summarys.summary')->with(['total'=>$total_projects]);
            }
```

in your blade :

```
<p>{{ $total }}</p>
```

Comment: This does not give you the number of rows impacted by a query, but rather the number of rows in the database.